# Tilde expansion not working when I hit tab on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-10.10, bashrc

I try to do this:

```
cd ~git\t
```

where the \t is tab character and I expect it to be expanded by bash_completion to this:

```
cd ~gitolite/
```

but it doesn't. I've uncommented the following lines in /etc/bash.bashrc and logged out and back in.

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have:

```
complete -d cd
```

try running this:

```
complete -o bashdefault -d cd
```

then try your `cd ~git\t` again.

If that works, add `complete -o bashdefault -d cd` to your `~/.bashrc`, or wherever you put your configs for bash.

Comment: That command did the trick, as long as I have it execute after bash_completion is sourced. I put it at the end of /etc/bash.bashrc with bash_completion enabled above it, then I had to comment out the bash_completion in ~/.bashrc, so now it will work for all users. Cheers!